# Image Effect on Hover w jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, image, effect

A few months ago, i ran accross a jQuery plugin which gave me a great effect once you moved your mouse over a thumbnail.
Actually, it made the image slide out in 4 pieces leaving some html content on it's place..here's a simple example image of what I'm looking for...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B25dA.jpg

please, if you now what it is, let me know!
thanks in advance,
Tamas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.queness.com/resources/html/slicing/index.html

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for jQuery UI Explode:

[UI/Effects/Explode](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Explode)

Comment: You can adjust the speed of the effect with the second argument, e.g. $(this).hide("explode", 1000); will take a second, by using 500 you'll get half a second, etc. You can also adjust the number of pieces the element dissolves to.